# RNA strings and amino acid string

Tags: python, phylogenetics, phylogeny, rna

Which of the following RNA strings could translate into the amino acid string PRTEIN? (Select all that apply.)

I am not sure if the following mass of amino acid is relevant to the question.

[image: mass]

```
CCAAGUACAGAGAUUAAC

CCAAGAACAGAUAUCAAU

CCACGUACUGAAAUUAAC

CCGAGGACCGAAAUCAAC
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite get the question but here's the answer and the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from Bio.Seq import Seq

for dna in ['CCAAGUACAGAGAUUAAC','CCAAGAACAGAUAUCAAU', 'CCACGUACUGAAAUUAAC','CCGAGGACCGAAAUCAAC']:
    print(Seq(dna).translate())
```

> PSTEIN PRTDIN PRTEIN PRTEIN

Comment: may I know where is the API code documentation for `.translate()` function call ?

Comment: Its Biopython part of the Bio package. Its not an API its a Python package

Comment: https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.Seq.html#Bio.Seq.Seq.translate

Comment: what is the opposite of `.translate()` function calls ?  I mean let's say I am given an amino acid string `CYCLIC`, how do I obtain all the possible combination of DNA strings before the translation process ?

Comment: Thats a separate question because it will involve degeneracy.

Comment: ok, let me ask in a separate question thread

Comment: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/19498/reverse-translation-from-amino-acid-string-to-dna-strings

Comment: Minor note: A sequence containing `U` usually means it is an RNA sequence, while `T` would hint at it being a DNA sequence. In eukaryotes, the DNA sequence is often not directly translated into the corresponding RNA sequence, because of effects like alternative splicing.

Comment: Thanks @RobertHass. Could be a virus?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do the translation yourself, using the genetic code in form of a dictionary from Biopython:

```
import Bio

# Load the genetic code (a mapping from RNA triplet to amino acid)
d = Bio.Data.CodonTable.standard_rna_table.forward_table
print('Genetic code:', d)
print()

# Use it to translate an RNA sequence into an amino acid sequence
s = 'CCAAGUACAGAGAUUAAC'
for triplet in (s[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(s), 3)):
    print(triplet, '->', d[triplet])
```

Printed result:

```
Genetic code: {'UUU': 'F', 'UUC': 'F', 'UUA': 'L', 'UUG': 'L', 'UCU': 'S', 'UCC': 'S', 'UCA': 'S', 'UCG': 'S', 'UAU': 'Y', 'UAC': 'Y', 'UGU': 'C', 'UGC': 'C', 'UGG': 'W', 'CUU': 'L', 'CUC': 'L', 'CUA': 'L', 'CUG': 'L', 'CCU': 'P', 'CCC': 'P', 'CCA': 'P', 'CCG': 'P', 'CAU': 'H', 'CAC': 'H', 'CAA': 'Q', 'CAG': 'Q', 'CGU': 'R', 'CGC': 'R', 'CGA': 'R', 'CGG': 'R', 'AUU': 'I', 'AUC': 'I', 'AUA': 'I', 'AUG': 'M', 'ACU': 'T', 'ACC': 'T', 'ACA': 'T', 'ACG': 'T', 'AAU': 'N', 'AAC': 'N', 'AAA': 'K', 'AAG': 'K', 'AGU': 'S', 'AGC': 'S', 'AGA': 'R', 'AGG': 'R', 'GUU': 'V', 'GUC': 'V', 'GUA': 'V', 'GUG': 'V', 'GCU': 'A', 'GCC': 'A', 'GCA': 'A', 'GCG': 'A', 'GAU': 'D', 'GAC': 'D', 'GAA': 'E', 'GAG': 'E', 'GGU': 'G', 'GGC': 'G', 'GGA': 'G', 'GGG': 'G'}

CCA -> P
AGU -> S
ACA -> T
GAG -> E
AUU -> I
AAC -> N
```

Note that the same RNA sequence can also be translated into another sequence of amino acids by shifting the reading frame 1 or 2 positions. For example, the RNA sequence `'CCAAGUACAGAGAUUAAC'` can be split into different triplets:

1. `'CCA', 'AGU', 'ACA', ...`
2. `'CAA', 'GUA', 'CAG', ...`
3. `'AAG', 'UAC', 'AGA', ...`

In biological systems, an mRNA would have a [start codon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start_codon) that marks the beginning of an open reading frame, which is often the triplet `AUG`.