# reverse translation from amino acid string to DNA strings

Tags: python, phylogenetics, phylogeny, sequence-analysis

what is the opposite of [.translate()](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.Seq.html#Bio.Seq.Seq.translate) function calls ?

I mean let's say I am given an amino acid string `CYCLIC`, how do I obtain **all the possible combinations of DNA strings** before the translation process ?

Note: I was told that [degeneracy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4135748/) has an important role in this particular aspect, but I am not entirely sure about the degeneracy calculation in the following screenshot highlighted in yellow color.

[image: degeneracy]

The degenerate code is as follows:

```
table = {
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
        'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
        'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
        'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',                 
        'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
        'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
        'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
        'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
        'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
        'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
        'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
        'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
        'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
        'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
        'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_',
        'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W',
    }
```

Comment: There isn't a function that will do the reverse translation, so it user code and requires the degenerate amino acid table. Degeneracy is important into primer design agreed. I'm not around for several days.

Comment: May I know where exactly did you obtain the degenerate code table ?

Comment: There everywhere, I got it from Geek for Geeks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the table above the solution for CYCLE is:

```
from itertools import product

prot = 'CYCLE'
degenDict = dict()
for v,k in table.items():
    if k in degenDict:
        degenDict[k].append(v)
    else:
        degenDict[k]=[]
        degenDict[k].append(v)
nucs = [degenDict[resid] for resid in prot]
for degenNuc in product(*nucs):
    print(''.join(degenNuc))
```

> TGCTACTGCCTAGAA
> TGCTACTGCCTAGAG
> TGCTACTGCCTCGAA
> TGCTACTGCCTCGAG
> TGCTACTGCCTGGAA
> TGCTACTGCCTGGAG
> TGCTACTGCCTTGAA
> TGCTACTGCCTTGAG
> TGCTACTGCTTAGAA
> TGCTACTGCTTAGAG
> TGCTACTGCTTGGAA
> TGCTACTGCTTGGAG
> TGCTACTGTCTAGAA
> TGCTACTGTCTAGAG
> TGCTACTGTCTCGAA
> TGCTACTGTCTCGAG
> TGCTACTGTCTGGAA
> TGCTACTGTCTGGAG
> TGCTACTGTCTTGAA
> TGCTACTGTCTTGAG
> TGCTACTGTTTAGAA
> TGCTACTGTTTAGAG
> TGCTACTGTTTGGAA
> TGCTACTGTTTGGAG
> TGCTATTGCCTAGAA
> TGCTATTGCCTAGAG
> TGCTATTGCCTCGAA
> TGCTATTGCCTCGAG
> TGCTATTGCCTGGAA
> TGCTATTGCCTGGAG
> TGCTATTGCCTTGAA
> TGCTATTGCCTTGAG
> TGCTATTGCTTAGAA
> TGCTATTGCTTAGAG
> TGCTATTGCTTGGAA
> TGCTATTGCTTGGAG
> TGCTATTGTCTAGAA
> TGCTATTGTCTAGAG
> TGCTATTGTCTCGAA
> TGCTATTGTCTCGAG
> TGCTATTGTCTGGAA
> TGCTATTGTCTGGAG
> TGCTATTGTCTTGAA
> TGCTATTGTCTTGAG
> TGCTATTGTTTAGAA
> TGCTATTGTTTAGAG
> TGCTATTGTTTGGAA
> TGCTATTGTTTGGAG
> TGTTACTGCCTAGAA
> TGTTACTGCCTAGAG
> TGTTACTGCCTCGAA
> TGTTACTGCCTCGAG
> TGTTACTGCCTGGAA
> TGTTACTGCCTGGAG
> TGTTACTGCCTTGAA
> TGTTACTGCCTTGAG
> TGTTACTGCTTAGAA
> TGTTACTGCTTAGAG
> TGTTACTGCTTGGAA
> TGTTACTGCTTGGAG
> TGTTACTGTCTAGAA
> TGTTACTGTCTAGAG
> TGTTACTGTCTCGAA
> TGTTACTGTCTCGAG
> TGTTACTGTCTGGAA
> TGTTACTGTCTGGAG
> TGTTACTGTCTTGAA
> TGTTACTGTCTTGAG
> TGTTACTGTTTAGAA
> TGTTACTGTTTAGAG
> TGTTACTGTTTGGAA
> TGTTACTGTTTGGAG
> TGTTATTGCCTAGAA
> TGTTATTGCCTAGAG
> TGTTATTGCCTCGAA
> TGTTATTGCCTCGAG
> TGTTATTGCCTGGAA
> TGTTATTGCCTGGAG
> TGTTATTGCCTTGAA
> TGTTATTGCCTTGAG
> TGTTATTGCTTAGAA
> TGTTATTGCTTAGAG
> TGTTATTGCTTGGAA
> TGTTATTGCTTGGAG
> TGTTATTGTCTAGAA
> TGTTATTGTCTAGAG
> TGTTATTGTCTCGAA
> TGTTATTGTCTCGAG
> TGTTATTGTCTGGAA
> TGTTATTGTCTGGAG
> TGTTATTGTCTTGAA
> TGTTATTGTCTTGAG
> TGTTATTGTTTAGAA
> TGTTATTGTTTAGAG
> TGTTATTGTTTGGAA
> TGTTATTGTTTGGAG